# Creating html tags using php but is there a way to avoid it in this scenario?

Tags: php

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<table><tr><td>' . $row["some"] . '</td><td>'. 
      $row["somenae"]. '<div>'. $row["some"] . '</div>
       </td></tr></table>';
```

Above is my php script and the array size is some 50 to 100 or may be 1000 also, so looping through 50 to 100 and creating html tags using php, Is it a good practise here? how can I avoid it. I don't want to create html tags like tables using php here but I have left no choice with.

I only want the values of variables of php and that should be inserted in between tables.

How can I avoid creating html tags using php in this type of scenario? I did  lots of my code using this way and some of them said why do you make server busy by creating unnecessary tags here but I did not find any better solution than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["some"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row["somenae"]; ?>
                <div><?php echo $row["some"]; ?></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

There, much better. This'll hardly get any prettier.

Whether this table structure makes sense is another topic.

Comment: I liked this way but i am excited to know how the tables are created dynamically without an echo statement

Comment: I can't quite tell if you're asking a question or not, but: that's the way PHP is designed to be used, *embedded inside HTML*. That's what the opening and closing `<?php ?>` tags are for.

Comment: @niko in the above, before putting the table elements, the php tags are closed - `?>`. Effectively, these tags are just normal html, but since they are still encased within the while loop (closing tags doesn't escape the loop) they are still repeated every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP Template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). So the work is done by the engine and you dont have to care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [template engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) to separate the display of data (HTML) from the data processing code (PHP).

Good summary of PHP template engines is [here](http://webification.com/best-php-template-engines).